# I'm trying to build an HTML file with Shruti font (gujrati Unicode ) but it is showing some random symbols

Tags: html, css, unicode, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build an HTML file with Shruti font (gujrati Unicode ) but it is showing some random symbols. I tried multiple ways like mpdf lib but am not able to import shruti font in it.

Comment: Code please....

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You must [declare the encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    body { font-family: Shruti; }
</style>
</html>
<body>
<h1>ગુજરાતી લિપિ</h1>
<p><b>ગુજરાતી લિપિ</b> એ
<a href="https://gu.wikipedia.org/wiki/ગુજરાત">ગુજરાત</a>
રાજ્યમાં વસતા લોકો દ્વારા લેખનકાર્યમાં વપરાતી લિપિ છે, જે લિપિમાં
<a href="https://gu.wikipedia.org/wiki/ગુજરાતી_ભાષા">ગુજરાતી</a>,
<a href="https://gu.wikipedia.org/wiki/કચ્છી_ભાષા">કચ્છી</a>
તેમજ કેટલીક અન્ય ભાષાઓ લખવામાં વાપરવામાં આવે છે.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because maybe some symbol are not supported by shruti font